# WCF Data Service vs WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services

I have been catching up with MVC4 Web API and WCF Data Service.  From the surface, they both seem to be able to work with oData in the consuming client.  I wonder which one is better for separation of concern (separate data service layer from UI layers).  In my current solution, I have a plain MVC 3 style Intranet project and a MVC Data Service project.  The 1st project has a Service Reference to the 2nd project.  My goal is to write the data service once and make it available to all projects that would need to access underline database.  When I read about Web API, it seems to me that the ApiControllers can return oData compliant result to the consuming client without MVC Data Service.  My confusion is how I am going to expose this Web API MVC project as a service endpoint.  Should I wrap it in WCF?  Thanks.

Comment: `how I am going to expose this Web API MVC project as a service endpoint` -- It's essentially a web server.  You hit it on port 80 with an Url.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just create a controller inheriting `ApiController` and decorate one action with `[Queryable]` attribute, Rest depends on your route setup. Easy-Peasy.

Which one better? Web API. Since it has all the goodness of HTTP and you are not restricted to ATOM format.

You may use [PocoHttp](https://github.com/PocoHttp/PocoHttp) for seamless access of the data from your client.

Comment: How about $metadata that we get from WCF which is not available in web api ? I think you are comparing mangoes with bananas...